# extracting the csrf token from the get request /api/csrf_cookie

Tags: reactjs, django, rest, fetch, csrf

My api end point is essentially /api/csrf_cookie which works great (verified on postman), however, my understanding of CORS is very limited, and am confused, how to GET the token on react (FYI backend is locally hosted on Django and I followed this - https://fractalideas.com/blog/making-react-and-django-play-well-together-single-page-app-model/).

I have tried multiple code snippets fro different sources, but they don't seem to work.

Here is the code, as of now.

```
const API_HOST = 'http://localhost:8000';

let _csrfToken = null;

async function getCsrfToken() {
    if (_csrfToken === null) {
      const response = await fetch(`${API_HOST}/api/csrf_cookie`, {
        credentials: 'include',
      });
      const data = await response.json();
      _csrfToken = data.csrfToken;
    }
    return _csrfToken;}

async function postRegister(email, password, cfmPassword, firstName, lastName, betaKey) {
    const csrfToken = await getCsrfToken();
    const response = await fetch(`${API_HOST}/api/register/`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
        'X-CSRFToken': csrfToken,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        credentials: 'include',
        body: JSON.stringify({
        email: email,
        password: password,
        cfm_password: cfmPassword,
        first_name: firstName,
        last_name: lastName,
        beta_key: betaKey
        })
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    return data.result;
    }
```

Update:

I use this hook-

```
 useEffect(() => {

        let csrfToken = null;

        async function getCsrfToken() {
            if (csrfToken === null) {
              const response = await fetch(`${API_HOST}/api/csrf_cookie`, {
                credentials: 'include',
              });
              const data = await response.json();
              csrfToken = data.csrfToken;
            }
            return csrfToken;}
        
        getCsrfToken();
      }, []);
```

And on page load, I get the token-

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

What to do next? Don't know how to call it into the form input.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6grR.png

Update 2:

Using this function:

```
function getCookieValue(name) {
    const cookies = document.cookie.split('; ');
    for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
      const cookie = cookies[i];
      const [cookieName, cookieValue] = cookie.split('=');
      if (cookieName === name) {
        console.log(`Found cookie ${name} with value ${cookieValue}`);
        return cookieValue;
      }
    }
    console.log(`Could not find cookie ${name}`);
    return '';
  }
```

It just doesn't find the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, CSRF cookies are secured using the HttpOnly attribute, meaning that they are not accessible from JavaScript. You typically don't submit CSRF tokens to APIs, they are mainly for HTML web forms.

Comment: Okay, so what do I do here? Essentially, the second function is taking in information from a signup form and sending it to another api endpoint.

Comment: How is the cookie set?

Comment: Not sure how to answer that question, so here is the Django view that defines the GET request:

@ensure_csrf_cookie
def get_csrf_cookie(request):
    return JsonResponse({}, status=200)

The corresponding api endpoint is url/api/csrf_cookie

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: To elaborate, the idea is to GET a CSRF token and then post if with subsequent forms. But, I have little to no clue how to do it.

Comment: The big idea with the CSRF cookie is that it is not accessible if your site is hacked using an XSS attack. Alternative is that you inject the CSRF token into the HTML page itself when the page is initially loadeD?

Comment: Interesting, thinking out loud, so like a useEffect hook? create a cookie variable and then call it in the hidden input?